# Fetching Data Using SOAPUI work but Unable to get data using PHP . Why?

Tags: php, wsdl, soapui

I am Trying to get the same data which I got using SOAPUI in PHP as I can't export in PHP.

See [My WSDL file](https://sandbox.webcomcpq.com/wsAPI/wssrv.asmx?WSDL). The function I am calling is *AUXTableAdminstration*.

If I am fetching the whole table the PHP code works but if I use anything  between `<web:xDoc>  </web:xDoc>` then I am having trouble.

### Input SOAP Request in SOAPUI

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webcominc.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <web:AUXTableAdministration>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <web:userName>UserName</web:userName>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <web:password>Password</web:password>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <web:action>EXPORTROWS</web:action>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <web:tableName>ContactData</web:tableName>
    <web:xDoc>
    <Root>
    <Columns>
    <Column>ContactInternalId</Column>
    <Column>ContactName</Column>
    </Columns>
    <SearchCriteria>
    <Value>12345</Value>
    <Value>TestName</Value>
    </SearchCriteria >
    </Root>
    </web:xDoc>
    </web:AUXTableAdministration>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am searching the row values using the above Request

### OUTPUT for SOAPUI

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <AUXTableAdministrationResponse xmlns="http://webcominc.com/">
    <AUXTableAdministrationResult>
    <Result>
    <Status>OK</Status>
    <Message>action 'EXPORT' for ContactData succeeded</Message>
    <Root>
    <Columns>
    <Column>CpqTableEntryId</Column>
    <Column>ContactInternalId</Column>
    <Column>ContactName</Column>
    <Column>CustomerInternalId</Column>
    <Column>Company</Column>
    </Columns>
    <Rows>
    <Row>
    <Value>1234</Value>
    <Value>1234</Value>
    <Value>Test Value</Value>
    <Value>86392</Value>
    <Value>Erin Test2</Value>
    </Row>
    </Rows>
    </Root>
    </Result>
    </AUXTableAdministrationResult>
    </AUXTableAdministrationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

### PHP file I am using with WSDL:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enable', '0');
    $username ="username";
    $password = "password";
    $action = "EXPORTROWS";
    $tablename= "ContactData";

    $xml ="<Root><Columns><Column>ContactInternalId</Column><Column>ContactName</Column></Columns><SearchCriteria><Value>86393</Value><Value>Erin Hensz</Value></SearchCriteria></Root>";

    $parameters= array('userName' => $username,'password' => $password,'action' => $action,'tableName' => $tablename,xDoc => $xml);
    $options = array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,'exceptions'=>true,'trace'=>1,'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE); 
    $client = new SoapClient('https://sandbox.webcomcpq.com/wsAPI/wssrv.asmx?WSDL' , $options);
    $data = $client->AUXTableAdministration($parameters);
    echo $result= $client->__getLastResponse();

    ?>
```

### PHP OUTPUT

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <AUXTableAdministrationResponse xmlns="http://webcominc.com/">
    <AUXTableAdministrationResult>
    <Result xmlns="http://webcominc.com/">
    <Status>NOK</Status>
    <Message>EXPORTROWS failed</Message>
    <Error>
    <ErrorCode>100000</ErrorCode>
    <Description>
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    </Description>
    </Error>
    </Result>
    </AUXTableAdministrationResult>
    </AUXTableAdministrationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```